# How to access this._screen in js class inside the constructor without super errors?

Tags: javascript, extends, super

I'm trying to create a class to handle information for a sprite using easeljs (called Rocket). In setting up the sprite I receive the error "Must call super constructor in derived class before accessing 'this' or returning from derived constructor", I've never used "super" before and so I tried to research it and it didn't solve my issue though I understand it a little more.

the code lines for setting up the sprite:

```
    this._sprite = assetManager.getSprite("uiAssets");
    this._sprite.mover = new Mover(this._sprite, stage);
    this._screen.addChild(this._sprite);
```

using this._stage instead of this._screen works, however I'm using multiple screens & I only want the Rocket sprite to be created and added to a specific screen.

Comment: Java or JavaScript?

Comment: if your class is extending another class you need to call the constructor of that class first

Comment: So JAVA or Javascript? Two different languages

Comment: can you tell us what the class is youre extending from and wether you know of its constructors ?

Comment: Please post the code that contains the `super()` call

Comment: @Doug The OP mentioned EaselJS, so I'm pretty sure it's JS. :)

Comment: there isn't any code that contains the super call, its javascript as tagged. the only class being extended is the screen class. how would i call the constructor of that class?

Comment: JS constructors are always called by using `new` like `new Screen()`

Comment: the class already extends screen, class Rocket extends Screen {